# SimpleDateFormat parsing a non date String

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm facing a problem with `SimpleDateFormat` that's parsing a non date String.
Here's the code used reduced to minimum:

```
public class TestAddressAgainstDate {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat oFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
    String m_sColumnValue = "3-21-1, Nihombashi Hama-Cho";
    Date oDate = oFormat.parse( m_sColumnValue  );
    System.out.println(oDate);
  }
}
```

the output is the following:

> Mon Sep 01 00:00:00 CET 4

The code this is from is testing whether the String is a date or not as the processor is also receiving date Strings from an XML.
My problem is that I can't change the behaviour of getting the field as String and I need to deal with also getting dates from.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

The original idea was to catch the ParseException and deal it as not a date but the japanese address ruined it. :-)

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I have another string which is causing problems even with `setLenien(false)`.

```
 String m_sColumnValue = "1-5-1 Ohtemachi, Chiyoda-Ku4";
```

anyone an Idea?

Comment: 3-21-1 is interpreted as an yyy3-21-d1

Comment: @reimeus you have any idea?

Comment: FYI leaving a message up here doesnt send me any notification

Comment: I thought so as help states that

Comment: I'm using a workaround which checks for a comma because afaik no date uses comma for seperating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`setLenient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient-boolean-) to verify the input date `String`

```
oFormat.setLenient(false);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked well. I haven't seen the `setLenient` option.

Comment: I would check it but I can't as I need to wait 10 minutes... Thanks for this reminder :-/